# How did this happen to my chainring?

Tags: repair, crankset

So, this happened.  All of this group of bolts but the one you see came out of my crankset:

[image]

My question is.. how exactly do all those bolts wriggle themselves loose !?  *How do I determine what bolt I need*?

Let's be honest: I'm not nice to transmissions. I weigh well over 200 lbs, my maximum measured output is about 1000 watts (briefly) and I ride in a fairly big gear all the time.

But what actually *happens* so that they vibrate out? I didn't think there was enough force to turn against threads offering lateral resistance...

I'm  more a commuter than a sportsman, should I suspect sabatoge?  (Ie, I leave it for 8+ hours at a time.)  To be fair, I hadn't inspected these in errr.... uggh.... well over 500 miles according to my odometer.

I used motorcycle chain lube (it was what the hardware store had.)

Comment: I've never seen that before.  Cranks come loose and fall off with appalling regularity (even though the symptoms of a loose crank should easily get the rider's attention).  I would imagine that a loose ring, though, would be less noticeable until it got near the end, especially if you were on a different ring with different bolts at the time.  (My guess would be that improper assembly is at fault.)

Comment: You would imagine correctly, failure was sudden.  I know this set made it *well* over 750 miles as it were.  Could you clarify your improper assembly guess?

Comment: Improper assembly would simply mean that the bolts were not properly torqued (or perhaps the wrong bolts were used) the last time the ring was replaced.  It's not really a rocket science operation, but anything can be screwed up, if you try hard enough.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm still suprised it would fail so gradually.

Comment: Well, the bolts aren't very long -- maybe 4 threads.  And the ring is sort of locked in place by the spider, so even with several bolts gone it wouldn't be obvious.

Comment: You state it both failed suddenly and gradually.  Which is it.  I suspect that chain ring was creaking when the bolts started to come loose.  When mine came loose I heard it.

Comment: The correct torque for those is pretty high (depends on chainset I suppose). You could use some Loctite thread lock (correct grade to allow bolt removal eg Blue 242) to avoid them working loose in future.

Comment: I mean: when it failed, it happened in moments: I didn't have any indication of something being wrong beforehand.  However, the amount of time it took to *get to* the failure points was probably over a year!  (Since the bolts were touched.)

Comment: Could someone be so kind as to tell me how to determine the size of the bolts on these things?

Comment: Could you be so kind as to just go to your LBS with the one left and ask for a set of 5?  And get some bicycle chain lube while you are there.

Comment: Well, my research indicates they all have the same thread/diameter, but not length.... I did, they're pricey!

Comment: Then take the whole bike to the LBS.  Really you expect us to know from a picture.  Bolt should extend to base of nut.  It is more expensive to not maintain a bicycle than it is to maintain a bicycle.

Comment: Ah, with all due respect sir, they knew from a picture!  (Or so it seemed.  Famous crankset, perhaps?)

Comment: If "they" knew from a picture you would have an answer. Really you think crank set alone dictates bolt length.  Ah, with all due respect sir, maintain your bike.

Comment: No... I didn't ask... they just tried to sell me them.  I should've!

Answer (score 2):

Chainring bolts do need to be checked/tightened at regular intervals, it's a part of the maintenance.
It it quite possible that they loosened in that 500 miles time and worked their way out; it's surprising that it wasn't more noticeable before it came undone. 
Some of the early indicators of loose chainring bolts include creaking and a rattle.

You can tighten them at home with the proper hex wrench and don't be afraid to strong arm it.

Comment: Great answer.  Welcome to the site.  And I would add use Loctite.

Comment: Come to think of it, I did hear some intermittent squeaking... but it never lasted very long, nor was it present so much as every other ride!  I'll step up my attentiveness.

Comment: @user1833028 - You should always be attentive of squeaks and clicks coming from your bike.  A properly-assembled bike in good working order should be silent, aside from chain noise.  And you should feel nothing through the pedals other than smooth motion.

Answer (score 0):

I have lost a bolt from my a chain ring and have been completely unaware of it for weeks.  I had to have it pointed out to me by a mechanic. In retrospect there was a little more rattle than normal.   I guess it is possible one could lose two and not know it either.  Once two come off there would be more rattling I would guess.  The amount would depend on where the remaining are aligned.  The rattle would probably then lead to the third one to come lose more easily at which point it would pivot.  I now check them frequently.

Comment: I have seen automobile wheels where 4 of the 5 lug bolts have come off, and the only clue was that the lug nuts were rattling around in the hubcap.